# Can I use Ubuntu with windows 7 starter?

Tags: windows-7

I've tried downloading Ubuntu 12.10 once before, but was unable to for some unknown reason. I only have Windows 7 starter edition- could that be the problem?

Comment: That cannot be the problem. You can definitely use Ubuntu with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

How can that be the problem? You can install any operating system you want in your hard drive, given that it has enough free space. Just back up your files!